# Frequency matrix - how to build in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have very little experience with Python and trying to build a frequency matrix which would summarize how many publication titles contain specific keywords, broken down by Faculty and keyword group (SDG). My current script uses test data and shows the occurrences when a title from a Faculty has a keyword from one of the keyword groups. I am not sure how to organise this into a matrix (count the occcurencies by Faculty and SDG) and output it to a csv.

My expected output would have the following 3 column headers:

Faculty,Number of titles with keywords, SDG (Keyword Group)

In addition to getting the frequencies, I also would like to find a way to be able to use keyword columns of varying length (data1). How can I do this?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
import pandas
import re   

data1 = {'SDG1':['Africa', 'Basic services', 'Class', 'Vulnerable','Wealth distribution'], 'SDG2':['Agricultural Orientation index',  'Agriculture', 'Consume', 'abcd', 'defg']} 
keywords = pandas.DataFrame(data1) 
keywords = keywords.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)

data2 = {'Title':['Africa blabla Class', 'Basic services blabla Class', 'Wealth abcdabcd', 'Wealth distribution 1', 'Wealth distribution 2','Consume blabla'], 'Faculty':['Eng', 'FHM', 'Eng', 'Architecture', 'Eng', 'Architecture']} 
titles =  pandas.DataFrame(data2) 
titles = titles.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
dict_Fac = pandas.Series(titles.Faculty.values,index=titles.Title).to_dict()

res = False
NumberofTitleswithKeywords=0
for key,value in dict_Fac.items():
    title =  key
    for column in keywords:
        patterns = keywords[column]
        res = False
        for pattern in patterns:                          
            #print('Looking for "%s" in "%s" ->' % (pattern, title), end=' ')

            if re.search(pattern, title):
                res = True                   
        if res:
            print (value)
            print("FoundKeywordfrom"+str(column))
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Provide an expected output perhaps?

Comment: thanks Henry, I added a note on the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I assume you simply want to check whether the titles contains keywords from either SDG1 or SDG2. This can be done by using `Series.str.findall`:

```
import pandas
import re

data1 = {'SDG1':['Africa', 'Basic services', 'Class', 'Vulnerable','Wealth distribution'], 'SDG2':['Agricultural Orientation index',  'Agriculture', 'Consume', 'abcd', 'defg']}

data2 = {'Title':['Africa blabla Class', 'Basic services blabla Class', 'Wealth abcdabcd', 'Wealth distribution 1', 'Wealth distribution 2','Consume blabla'], 'Faculty':['Eng', 'FHM', 'Eng', 'Architecture', 'Eng', 'Architecture']}
titles =  pandas.DataFrame(data2)
titles = titles.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)

sdg1 = r"|\b".join(i+r"\b" for i in data1["SDG1"])
sdg2 = r"|\b".join(i+r"\b" for i in data1["SDG2"])

titles["SDG1"] = titles["Title"].str.findall(sdg1,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
titles["SDG2"] = titles["Title"].str.findall(sdg2,flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print (titles)

#
                         Title       Faculty                     SDG1       SDG2
0          africa blabla class           eng          [africa, class]         []
1  basic services blabla class           fhm  [basic services, class]         []
2              wealth abcdabcd           eng                       []         []
3        wealth distribution 1  architecture    [wealth distribution]         []
4        wealth distribution 2           eng    [wealth distribution]         []
5               consume blabla  architecture                       []  [consume]
```

Comment: Thank you Henry! Yes, this is what I am after. So nice and simple solution...you have to know Python well to find it, though! Only issue here is the false match on abcdabcd vs abcd. I do not want to match on substrings...how can I adjust the script to avoid this?.

Comment: I can see your message about the edit, but can't see the solution....how can I avoid matching on substrings? 'wealth abcdabcd' should not have a match from SDG2 (keyword 'abcd').

Comment: @Gogota see edited above. Also if the answer helped, consider accepting the answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: I don't have access to your dataset. If you have edge cases, include them in your sample. You should not have this error if your column is `object` type.